# Why does my setInterval not display each number after 1 second?

Tags: javascript, node.js, events, setinterval

I have an application that is supposed to run a prime number every 1 second.

Everything works: console says "start" in the beginning and "end" in the end. However, it doesn't display each number after 1 second, instead it just displays everything at once.

## index.js:

```
var prime = require('./prime');

prime.on('start', () => console.log("Event Started"));
prime.on('prime', () => { });
prime.on('end', () => console.log("Event Ended"));
prime.start();
```

---

## prime.js:

```
var events = require('events');
var util = require('util');
util.inherits(PrimeNumber, events);
var prime = new PrimeNumber();
module.exports = prime;

function PrimeNumber() {
    events.call(this);
    var self = this;
    this.start = () => {
        self.emit('start');
        var interval = setInterval(() => {
            for (var counter = 2; counter <= 2000; counter++) {
                var notPrime = false;
                for (var i = 2; i <= counter; i++) {
                    if (counter % i === 0 && i !== counter) {
                        notPrime = true;
                    }
                }
                if (notPrime === false)
                    self.emit('prime', console.log(counter));
            }
            clearInterval(interval);
            self.emit('end');
        }, 1000);
    }
}
```

I've been trying to solve this one thing for a couple hours now, so any help is appreciated!

Comment: see the code inside the setInterval callback ... that gets run, every second ... all of it, not just some of it

Comment: So should I put the setInterval inside the for loop because I heard that it isn't a good idea?

Comment: no, you shouldn't - many intervals wil be started, you don't want that

Comment: also `self.emit('prime', console.log(counter));` is just `self.emit('prime', undefined);` because console.log returns undefined

Comment: What is this code supposed to do? emit a prime every second?

Comment: Yes, it's supposed to emit a prime every second.

Comment: Why not use classes? It would make your code more readable.

Comment: @Rahul - did that console output take 5 minutes to complete? because at 1 prime per second, it should take 303 seconds to complete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With minimal change to your code, could write it like this

```
var events = require('events');
var util = require('util');
util.inherits(PrimeNumber, events);
var prime = new PrimeNumber();
module.exports = prime;

function PrimeNumber() {
    events.call(this);
    var self = this;
    var startAt = 1; // starting position - 1 for the outer loop for each interval
    this.start = () => {
        self.emit('start');
        var interval = setInterval(() => {
            for (var counter = startAt + 1; counter <= 2000; counter++) {
                var notPrime = false;
                for (var i = 2; i <= counter; i++) {
                    if (counter % i === 0 && i !== counter) {
                        notPrime = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (notPrime === false) {
                    console.log(counter)
                    self.emit('prime', counter);
                    startAt = counter; // save the current prime, so we can start the next interval at the right place
                    return; // don't fall through, because we found a prime
                }
            }
            // if we get here, we've reached 2001 without finding a prime
            clearInterval(interval);
            self.emit('end');
        }, 1000);
    }
}
```

> a more modern take on this, using `class` - and a slightly simpler algorithm

```
const events = require('events');

class PrimeNumber extends events {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
    start() {
        let primes = [2];
        this.emit('start');
        this.emit('prime', 2)
        let interval = setInterval(() => {
            for (let counter = primes[0] + 1; counter <= 2000; counter++) {
                if (primes.every(p => counter % p !== 0)) {
                    primes.unshift(counter);
                    this.emit('prime', counter);
                    return;
                }
            }
            clearInterval(interval);
            this.emit('end');
        }, 1000);
    }
}
const prime = new PrimeNumber();
module.exports = prime;
```

Comment: I've added a more "modern" take

Answer (score 0):

You're clearing the interval the first time it runs which is preventing it from running again.

Here's a simplified version of your `setInterval` behaviour that shows it more clearly:

```
var interval = setInterval(() => {
    // for loop here

    clearInterval(interval);    // <-- You're clearing the interval here

    self.emit('end');
}, 1000);
```

The easiest thing might be to put an `if` around the `clearInterval()` call to control when you stop the timer.